# cron task doesn't run when first task have exception

Tags: exception, cron

I have a crontab line to perform 2 task like this:

```
0 3 * * * java -jar somthing.jar && java -jar something2.jar
```

my problem is that when first task have exception the second task doesn't run. i want to run second task after first task completed or have exception.

Comment: Why did you use `&&` if that wasn't what you wanted?

Comment: because i don't know what should be used! anyway ';' solve my problem, thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you use `;` instead of `&&`

In your case:

```
0 3 * * * java -jar something.jar ; java -jar something2.jar
```